# Cant Seem To Aligning Nav Bar on TOP of Webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html

Good day, 
I am a brand new computer wizard ~:) 
I have been creating this homepage however I am struggling aligning my navigation bar or even finding a way to make it work? I am using XML for two specific buttons that need to be in there. However, I have not been able to find a way it could work using my 'products.php' page. Any help would be lovely!

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.showcase::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/ProductImages/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.showcase:hover::after {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

.showcase:hover .content {
  filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px)
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-left: -145px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.content .logo {
  height: 101px;
  width: 310px;
}

.content .title {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.content .text {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.bg-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333333;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #333333;
  color: #f4f4f4
}

footer {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

.menuItem a {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}

.navmenuItem {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 70px;
}

.submenuItem {
  width: 300px;
}

.subMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  z-index: 1024;
}

.menuItemHover {
  display: block;
}

.subsubMenu {
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  left: 99%;
}

.anchorMenuItem {
  display: block;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- This is a comment tag -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>M.A.C</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="siteLayout.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="siteTheme.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
  <style>
    /* This is an internal style sheet */
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='Shop.js'></script>
  <script>
    var timer;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      // set a timed function call to wait for product xml to load
      timer = window.setInterval(function() {

        // Check if products have loaded
        if ($products === null) {
          // They haven't loaded
          return;
        } else {
          // They have loaded

          // Remove timer
          window.clearInterval(timer);

          // Populate the nav bar
          populateNav("navmenu");

          // Your $(document).ready() event script code goes below here -v



        }
      }, 100);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navmenu">
    <a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a>
  </div>

  <header class="showcase">

    <div class="content">
      <img src="ProductImages/logo.png" class="logo" alt="MAC">
      <div class="title">
        Welcome
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        M·A·C celebrates diversity and INDIVIDUALITY we are for All Ages, All Races, All Genders
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!----services -->
  <section class="services">
    <div class="container grid-3 center">
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Twitter</h3>
        <p> The Official MAC Cosmetics Twitter Channel</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>YouTube</h3>
        <p> The Official MAC Cosmetics YouTube Channel</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Instagram</h3>
        <p> The Instagram MAC Cosmetics YouTube Channel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="center">
          <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3> DELAY ON SHIPPING</h3>
          <p>We apologize for any inconvenience. Please take note of the revised shipping and delivery estimates for these items. Unless you cancel these items from your order, we'll continue to process and ship them as soon as possible.
          </P>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="center bg-dark">
    <p> &copy; MAKE-UP ART COSMETICS. ALL WORLDWIDE RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
<?php
// ******************************************************
// ** YOU ARE TO ADD YOU PRODUCT DATA INTO THIS ARRAY  **
// ******************************************************

    $productArray = array(
        "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"FACE\"><id>0001</id><title>STUDIO FIX FLUID SPF 15 FOUNDATION</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>26.00</price><description>A modern foundation that combines a natural matte finish and medium to full buildable coverage with broad spectrum UVA/UVB SPF 15/PA++ protection.</description><picture>0001.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"FACE\"><id>0002</id><title>PRO LONGWEAR CONCEALER</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>18.50</price><description>A lightweight, fluid concealer that provides medium to full coverage with a comfortable, natural matte finish.</description><picture>0002.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"FACE\"><id>0003</id><title>MINERALIZE SKINFINISH NATURAL</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>25.00</price><description>A luxurious, slow-baked domed face powder with low-level pearlized pigments that provide a dimensional yet natural-satin finish.</description><picture>0003.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"FACE\"><id>0004</id><title>MINERALIZE SKINFINISH</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>25.50</price><description>A luxurious, slow-baked, velvety soft, domed face powder with a radiant finish.</description><picture>0004.jpg</picture></product>\n",
        "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"EYES\"><id>0005</id><title>EYE BROWS STYLER</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>15.50</price><description>Self-propelling, self-sharpening, brow-defining – and now with an updated water-resistant formula and added spoolie. </description><picture>0005.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"EYES\"><id>0006</id><title>LIQUIDLAST 24-HOUR WATERPROOF LINER</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>17.00</price><description>A rich black liquid eye liner that combines long-lasting wear with a non-smudge, non-flake precision line.</description><picture>0006.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"EYES\"><id>0007</id><title>FLUIDLINE BROW GELCREME</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>17.50</price><description>Long-wearing waterproof gel in a pot that gives precise definition to brows.</description><picture>0007.jpg</picture></product>\n",
        "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"EYES\"><id>0008</id><title>EYE SHADOW X 9: AMBER TIMES NINE</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>26.00</price><description>This well-edited palette features a colour wave of amber hues that offer countless shade combinations.</description><picture>0008.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"LIPS\"><id>0009</id><title>MATTE LIPSTICK</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>17.50</price><description>This creamy rich formula features high colour payoff in a no-shine matte finish.</description><picture>0009.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"LIPS\"><id>0010</id><title>LIP PENCIL</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>14.00</price><description>A pencil designed for shaping, lining or filling in the lip. Lip Pencils have a smooth, creamy texture that is perfect for outlining lips or colouring them in.</description><picture>0010.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"LIPS\"><id>0011</id><title>PREP + PRIME LIP</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>14.00</price><description>A colour-free base to wear under lipstick. Adds light moisture, smoothes and refines the lips.</description><picture>0011.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"BEST SELLING\" sub-level-category=\"LIPS\"><id>0012</id><title>LIPGLASS CLEAR</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>15.50</price><description>A unique lip gloss that can create a glass-like finish or a subtle sheen.</description><picture>0012.jpg</picture></product>\n",

        "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"HYPER REAL GLOW\"><id>0013</id><title>STUDIO WATERWEIGHT SPF 30 FOUNDATION</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>28.00</price><description>Description Text 13</description><picture>0013.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"HYPER REAL GLOW\"><id>0014</id><title>135S LARGE FLAT POWDER</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>34.50</price><description>Because of its slightly flat paddle shape and silky bristles, this brush is best used for sheer washes of powder all over the face.</description><picture>0014.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"HYPER REAL GLOW\"><id>0015</id><title>HYPER REAL GLOW PALETTE / GET LIT</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>35.00</price><description>Enter the next dimension with Hyper Real Glow! This palette packs three hues of highlight for supercharged sci-fi radiance.</description><picture>0015.jpg</picture></product>\n",

  "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"HYPER REAL GLOW\"><id>0016</id><title>133S SMALL CHEEK</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>28.00</price><description>The elongated fluffy paddle shape allows for precise application, as well as easy blending.</description><picture>0016.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"BOOM BOOM BLOOM\"><id>0017</id><title>EYE SHADOW X 9/ CHERRY BLOSSOM PALETTE</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>26.00</price><description>This well-edited palette features a colour wave of warm neutral hues offering countless shade combinations. </description><picture>0017.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"BOOM BOOM BLOOM\"><id>0018</id><title>HIGHLIGHT POWDER/ BOOM, BOOM, BLOOM</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>20.00</price><description>A specialty powder in two shade waves that features a unique cherry blossom design embossed into the powder. </description><picture>0018.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"BOOM BOOM BLOOM\"><id>0019</id><title>STROBE CREAM</title><brand>MAC</brand><price>25.00</price><description>The ultimate quick fix for the skin. Super-powered with potent botanicals to refresh and moisten.</description><picture>0019.jpg</picture></product>\n",

    "<product top-level-category=\"WHATS NEW\" sub-level-category=\"BOOM BOOM BLOOM\"><id>0020</id><title>LIPGLASS / BOOM, BOOM, BLOOM </title><brand>MAC</brand><price>15.50</price><description>An exclusive lineup of four pink lip gloss colours for every skin tone that can create a high-gloss, glass-like finish or a subtle sheen.</description><picture>0020.jpg</picture></product>\n"


    );

// *******************************************************************
// ** YOU MUST NOT CHANGE ANY OF THE CODE BELOW THIS COMMENT        **
// ** IN THIS FILE UNLESS AUTHORISED TO DO SO BY THE MODULE LEADER  **
// *******************************************************************

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";

    // Check to see what we are sending
    if (empty($_GET))
    {
        // Send all products
        echo "<products>";
        for($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++)
        {
            echo $productArray[$x];
        }
        echo "</products>";
    }
    else if(array_key_exists('homepage', $_GET))
    {
        // The index.html is asking for carousel products
        echo "<homepageProducts>";

        $prodChosen = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i=$i+1)
        {
            echo "<prodID>00";

            // Generate product id
            $val = rand(1, 20);

            if ($i > 0)
            {
                $chosen = 0;

                // Check it has not already been chosen
                while ($chosen == 0)
                {
                    for ($v=0; $v < $i; $v++)
                    {
                        if ($prodChosen[$v] == $val)
                        {
                            $chosen = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if ($chosen == 1)
                    {
                        $val = rand(1, 20);
                        $chosen = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $chosen = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Debug line
            // error_log($val, 4);

            $prodChosen[$i] = $val;

            if ($val < 10)
            {
                echo "0", $val;
            }
            else
            {
                echo $val;
            }

            echo "</prodID>";
        }

        echo "</homepageProducts>";
    }
    else
    {
        // Must be a search
        echo "<results>";
        $engine[20][2];

        for ($x=0; $x < 20; $x++)
        {
            $engine[$x][0] = $x;
            $engine[$x][1] = 0;
        }

        // Only add products if there is an actual term
        if (array_key_exists('searchTerm', $_GET))
        {
            if (strlen($_GET['searchTerm']) > 0)
            {
                $bits = explode(" ", $_GET['searchTerm']);
                if (count($bits) == 1)
                {
                    //Only one term - check each product
                    for ($x=0; $x < 20; $x++)
                    {
                        $engine[$x][1] = substr_count(strtolower($productArray[$x]), strtolower($_GET['searchTerm']));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Multiple terms
                    // Check whole string of terms against the products
                    for ($x=0; $x < 20; $x++)
                    {
                        $engine[$x][1] = substr_count(strtolower($productArray[$x]), strtolower($_GET['searchTerm']));
                    }

                    // Check each individual term against the products
                    for ($x=0; $x < 20; $x++)
                    {
                        for ($y=0; $y < count($bits); $y++)
                        {
                            $engine[$x][1] += substr_count(strtolower($productArray[$x]), strtolower($bits[$y]));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Now sort them into count order
                for ($x=0; $x < 19; $x++)
                {
                    for ($y=$x + 1; $y < 20; $y++)
                    {
                        if ($engine[$x][1] < $engine[$y][1])
                        {
                            // Swap them
                            $tmp = $engine[$x];
                            $engine[$x] = $engine[$y];
                            $engine[$y] = $tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Only output the products with a count > 0
                for ($x=0; $x < 20; $x++)
                {
                    if ($engine[$x][1] > 0)
                    {
                        echo $productArray[$engine[$x][0]];
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        echo "</results>";
    }
?>
```

```html
<?php
```

I have included everything I have been working on, If it is unclear - I am a beginner! Please don't send any negativity! Thank you again

Comment: Why don't you use a framework like bootstrap... many css styles are pre-written and highly customizable with it. Includable iva cdn or directly - you should give it a try.

Comment: Ooo yes, I’ve heard of bootstrap but I haven’t used it before. Is there anything from there you recommend me using?

Comment: Sure - see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#placement

Answer (score 0):

This will keep'er at the top:

```
.navmenu {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've added it to your snippet:

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.showcase::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/ProductImages/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.showcase:hover::after {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

.showcase:hover .content {
  filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px)
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-left: -145px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.content .logo {
  height: 101px;
  width: 310px;
}

.content .title {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.content .text {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.bg-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333333;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #333333;
  color: #f4f4f4
}

footer {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

.menuItem a {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}

.navmenuItem {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 70px;
}

.submenuItem {
  width: 300px;
}

.subMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  z-index: 1024;
}

.menuItemHover {
  display: block;
}

.subsubMenu {
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  left: 99%;
}

.anchorMenuItem {
  display: block;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navmenu {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- This is a comment tag -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>M.A.C</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="siteLayout.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="siteTheme.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
  <style>
    /* This is an internal style sheet */
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='Shop.js'></script>
  <script>
    var timer;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      // set a timed function call to wait for product xml to load
      timer = window.setInterval(function() {

        // Check if products have loaded
        if ($products === null) {
          // They haven't loaded
          return;
        } else {
          // They have loaded

          // Remove timer
          window.clearInterval(timer);

          // Populate the nav bar
          populateNav("navmenu");

          // Your $(document).ready() event script code goes below here -v



        }
      }, 100);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navmenu">
    <a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a>
  </div>

  <header class="showcase">

    <div class="content">
      <img src="ProductImages/logo.png" class="logo" alt="MAC">
      <div class="title">
        Welcome
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        M·A·C celebrates diversity and INDIVIDUALITY we are for All Ages, All Races, All Genders
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!----services -->
  <section class="services">
    <div class="container grid-3 center">
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Twitter</h3>
        <p> The Official MAC Cosmetics Twitter Channel</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>YouTube</h3>
        <p> The Official MAC Cosmetics YouTube Channel</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Instagram</h3>
        <p> The Instagram MAC Cosmetics YouTube Channel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="center">
          <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3> DELAY ON SHIPPING</h3>
          <p>We apologize for any inconvenience. Please take note of the revised shipping and delivery estimates for these items. Unless you cancel these items from your order, we'll continue to process and ship them as soon as possible.
          </P>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="center bg-dark">
    <p> &copy; MAKE-UP ART COSMETICS. ALL WORLDWIDE RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps,